# how to get groups of a user in ldap

Tags: ldap, docker-compose, openldap, ldap-query

i am using openldap with phpldapadmin, and i'm trying to check what are the groups of a certain user. 
this is my scheme ...

[image: Ldap Scheme]

this is what i tried, but it didn't work

```
docker-compose exec openldap ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://openldap" -D "cn=admin,dc=openldap" -w admin -b "cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap" '(&(objectClass=*)(member=cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=openldap))'
```

PS: i'm new to ldap, [this](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) is the image i'm using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are tons of literature on LDAP and queries, that explain how to search for groups, with examples.

First the baseDN (-b) should be the top of your hierarchy: `dc=openldap`.

Second, you're searching from groups, so the filter should include `(objectclass=groupOfNames)`

Finally, you're searching for the groups a user is member of, and the filter should be `(member=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap)`

The resulting query is then:

`ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://openldap" -D "cn=admin,dc=openldap" -w admin -b "dc=openldap" '(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap))'`

This will return the group entries. If you are only interested in the name, add   `dn` at the end of the query.

Comment: groups is an ou that i greated .. why should i add this ? objectclass=groupOfNames

Comment: If you search under ou=groups, with a subtree scope, for all entries, the ou=groups entry will be returned. If you just want the groups, you need to specify a proper filter such as `(objectclass=groupOfNames)` (or whatever objectClass value used for your groups).

Comment: Could you link to some decent _literature on LDAP and queries_

Comment: The bible is and remains "Understanding and Deploying LDAP Directory Services, 2nd Edition" by Tim Howes, Mark Smith and Gordon Good. It's old but still relevent

Answer (score 6):

To get groups of user for user1 this search filter should be enough:

```
(&(memberUid=user1))
```

However note that group search attrribute may be different based on open ldap configuration. It can be member, uniqueMember, memberUid etc

[image]

Comment: memberUid is an attribute of the posixGroup. Not all groups are posixGroup. But with posixGroup, the suggested filter is the simplest one.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why the accepted answer does not work for me.
And the command works for me is:

```
ldapsearch -H "ldap://$server" -x -D "$user" -w "xxxx" -b "baseDN"  "(cn=notMe)" memberof
```

Comment: replace the notMe with your own info.

Answer (score 0):

Other variants of LDAP may require you to use:-b ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

```
ldapsearch -h ldap -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -x -w password -b ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com -s sub '(&(objectClass=groupOFNames)(memberuid=user1))' DN
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

In our LDAP, instead of groupOfNames/member I had to use **groupOfUniqueNames**/**uniqueMember**. The query is then:

`ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://openldap" -D "cn=admin,dc=openldap" -w admin -b "dc=openldap" '(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap))'`