# how to get groups of a user in ldap by members with attribute value

Tags: ldap, openldap

My question is very similar to [how to get groups of a user in ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341936/how-to-get-groups-of-a-user-in-ldap) but I want to be able to search a group whose member has attribute foo with value bar

ie, from the previous question instead of doing `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap))`

I want to do something like 
`(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=sn=bar))`
but it seems only the full DN can be used for such query. Is there another way to find groups for user matching a pattern?

Comment: Does your server have [`memberOf` enabled for users](https://www.adimian.com/blog/2014/10/how-to-enable-memberof-using-openldap/)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `memberOf` is available to you, you can search for the users instead of the groups:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(sn=bar))
```

(You might have to change the `objectClass` depending on what it is for users. I'm used to Active Directory, not OpenLDAP.)

Then you can read the `memberOf` attribute of the users you find.

*Update:* If you just want to find members of that group with that attribute then you can do it in one query by using `memberOf` in the query, and looking for the DN of the group:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(sn=bar)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,DC=whatever))
```

Comment: But can that be made in a single query? I'm using a library that I pass it the query for what I want and does operations based on RBAC. So I can't  do multiple queries

Comment: I see. I updated my answer with something that should work.

Comment: Thanks for that @GabrielLuci but that would imply I know the group. The objective is to get the group of someone of whom I only have partial information (i.e not full DN)

Comment: Sounds like you will have to do it in two steps then.

Comment: yep, I thought so. Thanks for confirming it!