# LDAP Query, two groups one with user and the other with user groups

Tags: ldap, jira

im new to LDAP and I would like query a set of data in LDAP

Ou A - has user group but no users
Ou B - has users but not user group

The users in B are linked to A via different group respectively, how can i link and query them out?
ive tried using membersof but dont seem to be working, do i need to put in the cn of each group?

Edit: i found a simliar post but it was in docker, i would like to translate it into jira's ldap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/puX2V.png
from [how to get groups of a user in ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341936/how-to-get-groups-of-a-user-in-ldap)

Comment: Please provide samples of your data and the queries you are trying.

Comment: for example
ou A - has user groups x and y
ou B - has users such as jake,mary,john, dale
and Jake and mary are in group X while john and dale is group y

i was doing (&(objectCategory=Group(|(ou=a,dc=domain,dc=com)(ou=b,dc=domain,dc=com)))

will the system be able to detect that they are linked as it is in the AD?

Comment: In general, LDAP queries cannot do "joins" like a typical relational database can. Usually, one would have to do two (or more) queries.

Comment: Are there any examples where i could have multiple queries in a "line/statement"?